# Installer tools suggestions

Tags: installation

I need to create an Installer for my company's product. Can anyone please suggest some tools to start with.

Requirements are:

1. Support for copying/editing/extracting etc
2. Support for Ant based targets
3. Support for adding custom Java code in the workflow
4. If JRE can be bundled along.
5. Need to bundle following application server: JBoss, Weblogic, Websphere
6. Cross platform support (Win/Linux/Solaris)
7. Support 32-bit and 64-bit platforms
8. Cloud support - To check for upgrades, download and install. Check for available patches etc.
9. Customizable by customers for adding their custom changes

Suggestions please.

Regards,

Comment: How about InstallAnywere? Have you explored it?  I have never really used it but i used to work in a project where it was being used for exactly the same purposes that you have listed above. That was 3 years ago. I had also heard back then that it had its own set of issues. I am not sure if they have been handled now.

Answer (score 0):

I have used Opsware (now HP)before, but it's not free. It will basically kick off RPMs or batch scripts to do the job. But you can simply create those without the product.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opsware